# How refresh the component of a form from an external class?

Tags: vb.net

The question is simple, I have `Form1` with a label and some other control. Now in an external class when I call a function I save a setting like this:

```
My.Setting.Update = Date.Now
```

this parameter is displayed on the label of `Form1` in the Load event, so I want to know how I can refresh the label text when this string is updated. I tried with `Form1.Refresh` from the other class but didn't worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: assigning the Date to Label.Text wont produce a clock or current data/time display of that is what you are trying to ask.  ie.  `Refresh()` wont update to the current time

Comment: In general, you can't. The external component has to be designed to allow this. If it only checks the value of the setting once, in the Load event, and never does it again, then you're out of luck.

Comment: Uhm no way for do this so

Comment: @CodyGray - By "external class" I think he just means "a class that is not Form1", not an actual 3rd party class library.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `public` sub on `Form1` called `RefreshFromSettings`.  This sub should set the label text to the settings value again, just like your code does now in the `Load` event.

Then in your external class, given a reference to the instance of `Form1` in a variable named `frm`, you can call that sub like this.

```
frm.RefreshFromSettings()
```

That will call your code that updated the label text.